# How do i slideToggle() text under images without them moving?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have 3 images in a table and 3 images in another table. I want to add a button under each image and when you click the button it will show some text ("info about img"). I have done that but the problem is, when i target one button all the other images moves down and the image above the button stays fixed. If i target all the buttons by giving them the same class name all the images stays fixed like i want but it shows the text for all images when i click the button, doesnt matter which one i click ofcourse.

/* THIS IS HTML */

```
<div class="span">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="imgContainer">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/pinkknitwear.jpg" alt="Pink knitwear" 
                title="Pink Knitwear">
                </div>
                <div class="imgButton">
                    <button value="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-cont">
                    <button class="info-btn">DETAILS</button>
                    <ul class="info1">Super nice!</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>

            <div class="imgContainer">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/greenknitwear.jpg" alt="Green Knitwear" 
                title="Green Knitwear">
                </div>
                <div class="imgButton">
                    <button value="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-cont">
                    <button class="info-btn">DETAILS</button>
                    <ul class="info1">Super nice!</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="imgContainer">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/redknitwear.jpg" alt="Red Knitwear" 
                title="Red Knitwear">

                </div>
                <div class="imgButton">
                    <button value="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-cont">
                    <button class="info-btn">DETAILS</button>
                    <ul class="info1">Super nice!</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

/*THIS IS jQUERY*/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".span").on('click', 'button', function() {
    $(this).closest('.span').find('.info1').slideToggle();

});
});
```

/*THIS IS CSS*/

```
.info1 {display: none;}


.btn-cont button{

 background-color: white; 
 border: 1px solid dimgrey;
 color: black;
 padding: 7px 10px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 flex-direction: row;

}

 .btn-cont button:hover {
 background: gainsboro;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

 .btn-cont {margin-top: 10px;}
```

[Example](https://gyazo.com/18e6f5f7d59a812db86013b1dc0d9095)
[Example](https://gyazo.com/f3c850e1b4722961273f3d41f7c85355)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this selector to toggle only the one element you're interested in:

```
$(this).next().slideToggle();
```

Then also set the vertical-align property of your table cells to top to prevent the others from moving.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zp5p7aqL/)**

Comment: omg it was this simple... i feel stupid now. its been awhile since i programmed tho. Forgive my ugly code. This worked, my problem is solved. Thank you so much! @j0869

Answer (score 0):

Edit js code to this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".span").on('click', 'button', function() {
        $(this).parents('.imgContainer').find('.info1').slideToggle();
    });
});
```